# Python reports error: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, user-interface

In Python I'm trying to create dynamic partition with GUI.

Here is the error I get:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> & C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe "c:/Users/Admin/Downloads/# Simple Python code.py"
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Downloads\# Simple Python code.py", line 108, in allocate_memory
    self.memory_simulation.allocate_memory(algorithm)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Downloads\# Simple Python code.py", line 40, in allocate_memory
    self.jobs[block_idx] -= process_size
    ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Code:

```
 import tkinter as tk 
 from tkinter import ttk

class MemoryAllocationSimulation:
def __init__(self, memory_size, os_size, initial_jobs):
    self.memory_size = memory_size
    self.os_size = os_size
    self.free_memory = memory_size - os_size
    self.jobs = initial_jobs
    self.allocation = [-1] * (len(initial_jobs) + 10)  # Adjust the size for potential new jobs

def best_fit(self, process_size):
    best_idx = -1
    for j in range(len(self.jobs) + 1):  # Include free memory as a potential block
        if j == len(self.jobs):  # Check for free memory
            if self.free_memory >= process_size:
                return j
        elif self.jobs[j] >= process_size:
            if best_idx == -1 or self.jobs[best_idx] > self.jobs[j]:
                best_idx = j

    return best_idx

def allocate_memory(self, algorithm):
    # Allocate memory for existing jobs
    for i in range(len(self.jobs)):
        process_size = self.jobs[i]
        if algorithm == "best_fit":
            block_idx = self.best_fit(process_size)
        elif algorithm == "first_fit":
            block_idx = self.first_fit(process_size)
        elif algorithm == "worst_fit":
            block_idx = self.worst_fit(process_size)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid memory allocation algorithm")

        if block_idx != -1:
            self.allocation[i] = block_idx
            self.free_memory -= process_size
            self.jobs[block_idx] -= process_size
        else:
            print(f"Job {i + 1} not allocated due to insufficient memory")

    # Allocate memory for new jobs
    new_jobs = [5, 30]
    for new_job in new_jobs:
        if algorithm == "best_fit":
            block_idx = self.best_fit(new_job)
        elif algorithm == "first_fit":
            block_idx = self.first_fit(new_job)
        elif algorithm == "worst_fit":
            block_idx = self.worst_fit(new_job)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid memory allocation algorithm")

        if block_idx != -1:
            new_job_idx = len(self.jobs) + len(new_jobs) - 2  # Index for new jobs
            self.allocation[new_job_idx] = block_idx
            self.free_memory -= new_job
            self.jobs.append(new_job)  # Append new jobs to the list
            self.jobs[block_idx] -= new_job
        else:
            print(f"New job {new_job} not allocated due to insufficient memory")
            new_job_idx = len(self.jobs) + len(new_jobs) - 2  # Index for new jobs
            self.allocation[new_job_idx] = -1

def first_fit(self, process_size):
    for j in range(len(self.jobs)):
        if self.jobs[j] >= process_size:
            return j
    return -1

def worst_fit(self, process_size):
    worst_idx = -1
    for j in range(len(self.jobs)):
        if self.jobs[j] >= process_size:
            if worst_idx == -1 or self.jobs[worst_idx] < self.jobs[j]:
                worst_idx = j
    return worst_idx 

 class MemoryAllocationGUI:
 def __init__(self, root):
 self.root = rootself.root.title("Memory Allocation Simulation")

    self.memory_simulation = MemoryAllocationSimulation(100, 5, [15, 20])

    self.algorithm_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Select Allocation Algorithm:")
    self.algorithm_label.pack(pady=10)

    self.algorithm_var = tk.StringVar()
    self.algorithm_var.set("best_fit")

    self.algorithm_combobox = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=self.algorithm_var, values=["best_fit", "first_fit", "worst_fit"])
    self.algorithm_combobox.pack(pady=10)

    self.allocate_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Allocate Memory", command=self.allocate_memory)
    self.allocate_button.pack(pady=10)

    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=('Job', 'Size', 'Block'))
    self.tree.heading('#0', text='Process No.')
    self.tree.heading('Job', text='Process Size')
    self.tree.heading('Size', text='Block No.')
    self.tree.pack(pady=10)

def allocate_memory(self):
    algorithm = self.algorithm_var.get()
    self.memory_simulation.allocate_memory(algorithm)
    self.display_memory_status()

def display_memory_status(self):
    self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())
    for i in range(len(self.memory_simulation.jobs)):
        process_size = self.memory_simulation.jobs[i]
        block_no = self.memory_simulation.allocation[i] + 1 if self.memory_simulation.allocation[i] != -1 else "Not Allocated"
        self.tree.insert('', i, text=f'Job {i + 1}', values=(process_size, block_no))

    free_memory = self.memory_simulation.free_memory
    self.tree.insert('', len(self.memory_simulation.jobs), text='Free Memory', values=(free_memory, ''))

   if __name__ == "__main__":
   root = tk.Tk()gui = MemoryAllocationGUI(root)
   root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This just needs a bit of debugging. In a failure case, what value is `block_idx` and how big is `self.jobs`? I assume you are trying to access an array entry that does not exist.

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: Comment out this `# self.root = rootself.root.title("Memory Allocation Simulation")`

Comment: @toyotaSupra: please don't edit a question with your own findings - they will be confusing to future readers, since they disagree with the question author's findings. You can [add a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOgFg.png) in the comments instead.

Comment: @halfer. Sorry it was my fault. I had to delte immediately. Thanks

Comment: No problem @toyotaSupra. I don't do Python - could you say whether the section starting `def __init__` needs to be indented inside `class MemoryAllocationSimulation:`? It looks to me like it should.

Comment: AttributeError: 'MemoryAllocationGUI' object has no attribute 'title'

Comment: @halfer Yes. The `def __init__` section needs to be brought within the Class code block by indenting it. As do the two other method defs  as they are also part of the Class. As already commented, all the indentation needs fixing.

Answer (score 0):

In MemoryAllocationSimulation.allocate_memory your code 'allocates' pending initial jobs `[15, 20]`. After that it allocates new jobs `[5, 30]`. While trying to allocate job `15` the 'allocator' correctly sees that two 'processes' are already running, namely `[15, 20]`. so it tries to 'allocate' at index `2` leading to the IndexError.
I think you should move the initial_jobs to their own list
and append the job before decrementing

```py
class MemoryAllocationSimulation:
    def __init__(self, memory_size, os_size, initial_jobs):
        ...
        self.initial_jobs = initial_jobs
        self.jobs = []

    def allocate_memory(self, algorithm):
        for i in range(len(self.initial_jobs)):
            process_size = self.initial_jobs[i]
            ...
            if block_idx != -1:
                ...
                # Append initial jobs to the list
                self.jobs.append(process_size)
                self.jobs[block_idx] -= process_size
            else:
                ...
        ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit: See my comment.

> Python reports error: IndexError: list index out of range.

The problem can be fixed.

On line 37 change this:

```
if block_idx != -1:
```

to:

```
if block_idx == 1:
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Out result:

```
Job 1 not allocated due to insufficient memory
Job 2 not allocated due to insufficient memory
Job 1 not allocated due to insufficient memory
Job 3 not allocated due to insufficient memory
Job 4 not allocated due to insufficient memory
New job 30 not allocated due to insufficient memory
Job 1 not allocated due to insufficient memory
Job 2 not allocated due to insufficient memory
Job 3 not allocated due to insufficient memory
Job 4 not allocated due to insufficient memory
Job 5 not allocated due to insufficient memory
New job 30 not allocated due to insufficient memory
```